# Problems in VBA with Bloomberg function on a LOOP

Tags: database, vba, bloomberg

I'm trying to use this code to introduce a formula from A2 to the end of my database in steps of two cells.

```
Sub addbdh()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

n = Selection.Count

For i = 1 To n

Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "BDH(""A"" & "i * 2 - 1", "A1", "B1, "hoy()")"

Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get an error on the instruction:

```
Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "BDH(""A"" & "i * 2 - 1", ""A1"", ""B1"", "Today()")"
```

specifically in the "i * 2 - 1" part, I get an Excel MsgBox which says "Expected end of statement" (in spanish: "se esperaba: fin de la instrucción".

¿Could anyone help me to find the error on the code?

Tank you so much.

Comment: Formulas in excel cells starts with a "=..."

Comment: And you are misusing the `""`

Comment: Try "=BDH(""A""" & i * 2 - 1 & ", ""A1"", ""B1"", TODAY() )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `.Formula` shows the real English formula. Whatever your language is. Thus, `Hoy()` should be changed to `Today()`.

In general, try like this:

```
Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "=BDH(A" & i * 2 - 1 & ", A1, B1, Today())"
```

In general, when you have a problem like "How to translate a working Excel formula to VBA" do the following:

1. Select the working formula in Excel.
2. Run the following code.
3. Take the formula from the immediate window and fix it a bit to put the variable `i * 2 - 1`.

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

Comment: I think there is also a `"` missing before the first `&`, and probably two useless around `Today`

Comment: With: `Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "=BDH(""A"" & i * 2 - 1, ""A1"", ""B1"", Today())` I don't get the error anymore, but instead of that I get a wrong formula, having in my cells: =BDH("A" & i * 2 - 1; "A1"; "B1"; HOY()),

Comment: @Mauro - check the edit, it should work, only `4` `"`.

Comment: @VincentG - I don't have `BDH`, but I think 4 `"` would be enough.

Comment: @Vityata neither do I, but yes BDH has probably `Range` arguments and not `String` ones. ;)

Comment: I have edited my last comment, It only worked to print a wrong formula, I could get the equivalent element in english and it's in fact TODAY()

Comment: @Mauro - welcome. Feel free to accept the answer, once you can.